# Stark to Killian - Serious? Or messing with him?

Tags: marvel, iron-man, iron-man-3, marvel-cinematic-universe

In *Iron Man 3*, Aldrich Killian introduces himself to Tony Stark and the two of them (along with numerous partygoers) end up in an elevator together.
As everyone is leaving the elevator, Tony quietly says to Killian that he is fascinated by the idea of working with him and will meet him on the roof later to discuss it.

Of course, he never shows.

**My question is, in saying this to Killian, was Tony serious?**

Did he

- just get distracted by women and booze (completely plausible)?  Or,
- was he doing it maliciously to get rid of a pest (also somewhat plausible)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Tony Stark is a known douche bag, and that incident happened before his harrowing experience in Afghanistan had humbled him a bit. It was obvious that Tony was completely focused on *scoring* with the beautiful Dr. Hansen at the time and was completely uninterested in what Killian had to say. So I would say that Tony lead Killian on a wild goose chase just to get rid of him.

Comment: I think Tony's/RDJ's body language and facial expressions in that scene totally support this answer.

Comment: And not forgetting the fact that it was said with the very well executed Starkastic tone!

Comment: I know pre Iron Man I Tony was (even more) arrogant, but the thing he did to Killian was plain cruel, that's other thing about Iron Man III that I dislike, for me Iron Man III is not canon, and It really has nothing to do with any of the other movies. </rant>

Comment: @anakata - Because Tony was a complete asshole? But that *is* canon.

Comment: But that is just plain mean, he could have dismissed the cripple over excited Killian in a million ways, but no, he choose to have the poor guy going to the roof to wait for him forever, I think Tony is the real villian of Irom Man III, Tony and Shane Black.

Comment: @anakata - Which is true to canon. Before the incident in Afghanistan Tony was a complete and utter asshole, not just arrogant.

Comment: I personally don't like that, and since the movies have their own canon, and before Iron Man III the only glimpse of Tony we get before Iron Man is what we see the first minutes in Iron Man I, why making him a jerk?, an arrogant, selfish, self centered, ladies man, OK, but a complete jerk, I just don't like that. But I guess that's what Shane Black brought into the table, so, it's just the way it is... (and that is why I personally don't consider Iron Man III as canon, and neither the star wars prequels...)

Comment: @jsedano: What on earth...? So Iron Man III remains totally true to the canon and established character story, and due to that you're going to wipe it out of history? Weird.

Comment: Honestly, even in the comics, there are several instances where POST-Iron Man Tony is a @%!^&.